# Replace some string in div?

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have string like this:

```
$str = '<div> text echo <div class="code">echo "test!";</div> </div>';
```

How to replace an `echo` with `font` tag?

for example on out must be string looks like that:

```
$str = '<div> text echo <div class="code"><font color="green">echo</font> "test!";</div> </div>';
```

I've tried

```
$str = preg_replace("/<div class='code'>(echo)<\/div>/Usi",'<font color="green">echo</font>',$str);
```

but make no sense, so how I can do it?

**update** so seems this is a *solution*:

```
$str = '<div> text echo <div class="code">echo "test!"; echo "very test!";</div> </div>';

/*$str = preg_replace('/(<div class="code">.*?)(echo)(.*?<\/div>)/si',
       '$1<font color="green">$2</font>$3', $str);*/

$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(<div class="code")(.*?)(<\/div>)/si',
    function ($matches) {
        return $matches[1].str_replace('echo','<font color="green">echo</font>',$matches[2]).$matches[3];
    },
    $str);

echo $str;
```

Comment: `str_replace('echo', 'another string', $text)`

Comment: @JasonOOO watch the staff! `echo` must be replaced only in `code` div!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, to cope with multiple replaces, could use preg_replace_callback.

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(<div class="code")(.*?)(<\/div>)/si',
    function ($matches) {
        return $matches[1].str_replace('echo','<font color="green">echo</font>',$matches[2]).$matches[3];
    },
    $str);
```

the inner 'function', can actully perform multiple replacements on $matches[2]. That will only be code inside a code block.

(not it still doesnt work if there are nested  inside the code div!)

Comment: Thanx, but how to apply this? Here I have some error: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f943c1e0357775a0d35b75c498b90acb3cd17384

Comment: Ah, I left in a syntax error as a initiative test! (really it was just a typo...)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = preg_replace('/(<div class="code">.*?)(echo)(.*?<\/div>)/si',
       '$1<font color="green">$2</font>$3', $str);
```

- fixed the quotes
- allowed for text either side of the echo (the .*?)
- captured the before/after text so can be included in the replacement.
- used $2 instead of echo in the replacement, because your regex is not case sensitive, it maintains the case of the original.
- removed U, because made the two searches ungreedy. (but thats mostly a personal preference)

Comment: well, I have some problems with it. If I have a few `echo`s in my string it will work only for the first one? example str: **$str = '<div> text echo <div class="code">echo "test!"; echo "very test!";</div> </div>';** on out: `<div> text echo <div class="code"><font color="green">echo</font> "test!"; echo "very test!";</div> </div>`

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/65a6d3296f73867ede65c599e3b7f0223b4968ab

Answer (score 0):

your quotes is false,

```
preg_replace("/<div class='code'>(echo)<\/div>/Usi",
```

also is that:

```
preg_replace('/<div class="code">(echo)<\/div>/Usi',
```

and your regular is also false, maybe can test this:

```
$str = '<div> text echo <div class="code">echo "test!";</div> </div>';
$match = preg_replace('/<div class="code">echo(\s*.*)<\/div>/Usi','<div class="code"><font color="green">echo</font>'."\\1".'</div>',$str);
echo $str;
```

maybe you can use str_replace function, such as

```
$str = '<div> text echo <div class="code">echo "test!";</div> </div>';
$search = '<div class="code">echo';
$replace = '<div class="code"><font color="green">echo</font>';
$str = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: string can be different, not only `<div class="code">echo`, but also `<div class="code"> test echo "test"; echo "hmmm...";`

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '<div> text echo <div class="code">echo "test!";echo "test!";</div> </div>';

    // extract the content in the <div class="code">
    preg_match('/<div class="code">(.*)<\/div>/Usi',$str, $matches);
    // $matches[1] is the content and excute replace singly
    $result = str_replace('echo', '<font color="green">echo</font>', $matches[1]);
    // let the replace result insert the origin str
    $str = preg_replace('/<div class="code">(.*)<\/div>/Usi', '<div class="code">'.$result.'</div>', $str);
    echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this your answer:

```
$str = '<div> text echo <div class="code">echo "test!";echo "test!";</div> </div><br><div> text echo <div class="code">echo "test!";echo "test!";</div> </div>';

// extract the content in the <div class="code">
preg_match_all('/(<div class="code">.*<\/div>)/Usi',$str, $matches);
$i = 0;
$newStr = '';
$arr = preg_split('/<div class="code">(.*)<\/div>/Usi', $str);
foreach($matches as $match) {
    // $matches[1] is the content and excute replace singly
    $result = str_replace('echo', '<font color="green">echo</font>', $match[1]);
    $newStr .= $arr[$i].$result;
    $i++;
}
// add the end of the str
$newStr = $newStr.$arr[$i];
echo $newStr;
```